# RegExp matching part of a string

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching, match, flags

I've put together a search function that looks through lots of divs to match a string to information in its data attributes and I'm using regular expression to do this.

This is the regular expression I'm currently using which is working.

```
var regExPattern = "gi";
var regEx = new RegExp(filter, regExPattern);
// filter is the text that the user searches.
```

I need to change the pattern so it can match part of a string e.g. it can match '`world`' in '`hello world`'. But at the moment mine only works if you type in the full string '`hello world'`.

I had a read on the [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) page about regular expressions, and I think the flag I need to use is `\S`. So I changed my `regExPattern` to `"gi/\S\w*/"`...but this doesn't work. I think I'm going really wrong with how to use the flags. Please can someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: You have your terms all mixed up. The `"gi"` is not a regex pattern, and `\S` is not a flag. This `"gi/\S\w*/"` appears to be an attempt to mix regex flags with regex syntax. I think maybe you should start from the top and understand more of the basics first.

Comment: @thesystem I'm quite new to regular expressions so I thought I was going about this all wrong. How do I use a mix of both flags and regex syntax? (If I even need to that is).

Comment: You first make a regular expression. That's the pattern matching part. The flags are just settings that modify the behavior of the regex. For example, the `i` flag makes the entire regex pattern case insensitive, and the `g` flag causes the regex to search an entire string instead of stopping at the first match.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll get back to the drawing board and have another go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it wasn't a problem with RegEx patterns or flags, as they were working as I'd hoped by searching through a whole string anyway, but it was a problem with my search function in total. [Please see this later question I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759234/searching-through-multiple-data-attributes/14759387#14759387).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this?

```
var aa = 'hello world';
var bb = 'world';
var cc = new RegExp( bb );
alert( aa.match( bb ) );
```

[**ref**](http://github.com/svnpenn/bm/blob/gh-pages/yt.js)