# Searching through multiple data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, search, custom-data-attribute

I'm putting together a search function that searches through multiple data attributes on a lot of divs on a page. Below is the code I have working for this. My problem I've come across is that it only seems to search the first word each data attribute **except** the last one.

```
var filter = $(this).val();
var regExPattern = "gi";
var regEx = new RegExp(filter, regExPattern);   
$(".box").each(function(){
   if (
      $(this).data('attr1').search(regEx) && 
      $(this).data('attr2').search(regEx) &&
      $(this).data('attr3').search(regEx) &&
      $(this).data('attr4').search(regEx) < 0
   )
   {
      //Do Something
   } 
   else 
   {
      //Do Something else
   }         
});
```

I've put together a [fiddle that replicates this problem here.](http://jsfiddle.net/xNwbw/)

I've tried different combinations of searching... such as putting all the data attributes into an array and then searching elements one by one, but that takes along time to complete.

I would be much appreciated if anyone can help with this?

Comment: Why do you only check the search index for `attr4` to be -1, and not for the others?

Comment: @Bergi I thought as the && would include all 4 data attributes... which it does, but for the first 3 attributes it only matches the first word, if it's separated by a space it neglects it from the search, as shown in my fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is confusing. [`.search()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) returns the index of a match or `-1`. So it yields a falsy value (`0`) only when the regex is found at the start of the string, and a truthy number otherwise. So change it to

```
  $(this).data('attr1').search(regEx) < 0 && 
  $(this).data('attr2').search(regEx) < 0 &&
  $(this).data('attr3').search(regEx) < 0 &&
  $(this).data('attr4').search(regEx) < 0
```

Or, since you don't need the position, switch to [`regEx.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: ok I'm still fairly new to this so if possible please can you suggest a better way around this?

Comment: Basically I've got 200+ divs on a page with 6 unique attributes each.. I need to search all 6 div attributes for every div. What I've added seems to work fine except if any of the data attributes (minus the last one) has a space in it.

Comment: WTF I swear I tried that and it didn't work... but have just tried it again and it works! I am confused but Thank you :)